# Employer has lost my contract where do I stand?

Tags: human-resources, united-kingdom, contracts

I requested a copy of my contract but my HR department have said they have lost it / do not have a copy. I have lost my copy. By law should they have one on file? Where do I stand with requesting a copy? Can I put a complaint in?  I have requested one as I have disciplinary meeting regarding my absence. I have genuine reasons doctors notes etc but feel like I am been treated unfairly as the manager has disliked me from the start. Would this help with my grievance I have raised?

Comment: Did you also lose your copy of the contract? Are you anticipating any dispute with your employer?

Comment: What jurisdiction are you in?

Comment: Where you stand cannot be answered without specifying what country or state you are in. Employment law will determine what your options are and how important your contract is. You should probably also clarify why you are suddenly after a copy. Put on hold pending clarification.

Comment: I live in the UK and I have had a few occasions where I have had time off work 2 of them I have doctors notes for one I was involved in a car crash the night before so went into work later the following day, one occasion I was injured at work and one was just a 24 hour virus so I feel that this has been unfair dismissal as the manager has had a problem with me for a while now. But yes unfortunately I have lost my contract. My solicitor is a family friend snd asked for a copy but is away on vacation at the moment. Thank you for the help

Comment: You probably need a copy of the employee hand book and discipline /grievance procedure as this is what defines the process for poor attendance btw the short absences you quote are not enough for a poor attendance discipline.

Comment: In the US you would be unable to negotiate back to the terms of your original agreement after the contract had been agreed to (which, we can presume since you are working and being paid). So the only real option you have would be to create a new contract. But, if they fired you for those days off - you could not prove it was in your contract that it was allowed, and they could not prove it was not. It sort of enters a legal gray area... I'd seek advice from an attorney familiar with local employment laws if it does become a problem.

Comment: They took me to a disciplinary meeting and as you said there was not enough absence to even hold a disciplinary meeting. But now they have added an absence in that was not counted as they sent me home from work. I was wondering if there was anything in my contract regarding this as they sent me home.

Comment: If you believe they are in breach of the contract it is up to you to prove that fact typically.  This is typically for conditions that are not assumed under any other legal guidance.  How you provide that proof is honestly up to you

Answer (score 11):

You didn´t state your country, so I this answer give you more of a general idea. If you update your question we can be a little bit more specific.

In absence of a written contract, legal baseline and precedence will probably set the rules that apply.

If there really is no copy both on your and your employers side, setting up a new one in paper should be beneficial for both parties, as it will remove ambiguities and thus lower the risk of litigation.

Comment: @bdsl: No, contracts are for the benefit of both parties, as you have written proof what was agreed upon. For example, here in Germany the required minimum vacation time is 4 weeks, but most companies grant 6 weeks by contract.

Comment: You might be right @Daniel. Now I think of it there's a low minimum level of sick pay here in the UK, but many contracts specify that the employees normal pay continues when they are sick instead.

Comment: On top, the OP should have a copy of the contract that can jsut be copied and notarized and handed over to the HR department. There isa reason you sign 2 copies and keep one.

Comment: did you reat *if there really is no copy both on your and your employers side* - I assumed that OP had none- If he had, why would he go to HR to get one?

Comment: Presumably the OP has also lost his copy.

Comment: I though all contracts would go onto a system? Hence why I contacted HR?

Comment: @Holly Your company should have all the contracts stored safely. If they lose your contract that's extraordinary incompetence.

Comment: Yeh thats what they are claiming to have lost it but I think it's a cover up to be honest for such a big organisation you think they would have certain standards and procedures in place!

Answer (score 1):

I'm based in England, but I assume the principles are similar in many countries.

Legally a contract is a particular type of agreement - it is not a piece of paper. So as long as you and your employer have (or had) an agreement that you will work for them and they will pay you, you have a contract. If there is ever a dispute that goes to court you would be able to find evidence of the existence of this contract, e.g. documents or emails about your work, your bank statements, witness testimony that describes your employment.

If you also don't have any copy of the contract document then there may be limited evidence on what the detailed terms of the contract are. There are likely to be local laws that specify some details of employment contracts, "unless otherwise specified". In the case of any dispute relating to your work a court would have to use a combination of the laws setting these default terms, and evidence based guess work as to what your contract is likely to be.

Comment: "*I assume the principles are similar in many countries.*" They are not.

Comment: I thought this was general enough to be widely applicable. Which part is not true in many countries?

Comment: Well the US usually doesn't use contracts for one. Employment laws and regulations on implied contracts are different everywhere, there's the issue of determining what kind of evidence really has legal value, you have no idea why the OP is so what aspects of the contract might be relevant, ...

Comment: The US may not generally use a written contract document, but I think there is legally a contract. In much of the US the implied terms allow either side to terminate employment at any time, but its still a contract. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At-will_employment and note the mentions of contract on that page.

Comment: I would say that a contract with the contract paper lost is not the same as an implied contract. If you signed a contract, and then the paper is lost, all the terms in the written contract remain valid - they are not overwritten by the legal terms for implied contracts. It just may hard to prove the contents :-(

Comment: For example, I have rights to annual holidays that exceed the legal minimum. If all copies of my contract get lost, I still have the same rights.

Comment: That's right of course Gnasher. It's just a question of what evidence of the contract you would have to show a court if your employer denied that those rights were ever in the contract.

Comment: @Lilienthal the USA is the odd one out when it comes to contracts

Comment: @bdsl You would have to show evidence, not proof. Evidence could be for example the contracts of all your colleagues (company lost my contract and they claim I have less holidays than everyone else - wouldn't be believed).

Comment: How would you prove they have lost your contract? They have said when I called the that they have so I have followed this up with an email so I have proof? What actions can I take against them?

Comment: @gnasher729 agreed.

Comment: @Holly: In the end, thinks might go to a civil court. And the judge in a civil courts decides what's most likely. If your ten colleagues all had contracts with the same term, and the company tells the court that you had no contract when you say you have one, then the judge isn't going to believe the company.

Comment: Ok thank you. Hopefully I will get some where next week have a few numbers to call now.